# "Vigenere" : String lowercasing program is appending character for some inputs

Tags: c, cs50

I'm finding that my very basic code to lowercase a string is sometimes outputting an extra character. If I run *vigenere* with some inputs, it works correctly:

```
~/workspace/pset2/vigenere/ $ ./vigenere tweedDLed
tweeddled
```

But for other inputs, it inserts an extra character at the end:

```
~/workspace/pset2/vigenere/ $ ./vigenere tweedDLedf
tweeddledfB
```

or...

```
~/workspace/pset2/vigenere/ $ ./vigenere bkls33bf
bkls33bfW
```

What is going on here? I am not finding anything with the debugger as the character array is not displayed. This is my code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]){
    if (argc!=2){
        return 1;
    }
    else{

        int n = strlen(argv[1]);
        char cipherKey[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cipherKey[i]=tolower(argv[1][i]);
        }


        printf("%s\n",cipherKey);


    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n",cipherKey);` --> `printf("%.*s\n", n, cipherKey);`

Comment: It is good to terminate the string with zero. Otherwise I am really surprised that you have only one letter more printed :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate space for the string termination character, and you need to terminate your string. Otherwise, you leave your string unterminated, `printf` may read out of the string's bounds yielding undefined behaviour (e.g. in form of "weired" output). You could correct this as follows:

```
    int n = strlen(argv[1]);
    char cipherKey[n+1];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cipherKey[i]=tolower((unsigned char)argv[1][i]);
    }
    cipherKey[n]='\0';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been struggling all day with this.

Comment: May I copy and paste your answer to this thread? https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/6so665/vigenere_lowercasing_script_inserts_extra/

Comment: It looks like it also works to simply make the `<` a `<=` in the for loop, because the nth character in the string that is being lowercased is also `\0`. That looks a little cleaner to me. :)

Comment: Yes, it will work with `<=n` as well, leading to a call to `tolower('\0')'; Not sure if it is cleaner; I personally prefer to make things (in this case string termination) explicit; but it's clearly just a personal preference.

Comment: @StephanLechner As you like explicit: `tolower(some_char)` can be _undefined behavior_ with `some_char < 0`.  Use `tolower((unsigned char) some_char)` to avoid that problem.